# writing ClientRequest for scgi with node.js

Tags: node.js, scgi

I want to write an scgi version of [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.request), which returns an instance of [`http.ClientRequest`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.ClientRequest). Of course, I'd write the equivalent but for scgi.

I'm wondering what I should go about extending or where I should begin. I can handle the scgi part, I'm just wondering how to implement it such that it's *more or less* a drop in replacement for `http.request`. In other words, used the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just take the API specification from [the node documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html) and reimplement it.